# Simple parametric shape question

Tags: geometry, parametric

Given the following vector, can someone tell me what geometric role the constant b plays? Assume I can measure the constants a (amplitude) and v_0 (velocity of midpoints) directly. I have been told that b represents the 'curviness', but when using a curvature definition for b, the graph looks nothing like it should.

[Here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/rq7vczx9us) is a link to the graph if that helps

$$
\vec{s} = (v_{0}t+b\cos(2t))\hat{x}+a\sin(t)\hat{y}
$$

Comment: It looks like 'curviness' to me.

Comment: How can this be expressed quantitatively. The best I can come up with would be treating the amplitude like the radius of a circle. Then the curviness should be b=1/a, but this is too small to produce the curving effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a better understanding, I'd suggest to study the curve for $v_0=0$:
$$
x=b\cos(2t)=b(1-2\sin^2t)=b\left(1-2{y^2\over a^2}\right)=b-{2b\over a^2}y^2.
$$
This is the equation of a parabola, intersecting the $y$-axis at $y=\pm a/\sqrt2$ and with vertex $V=(b,0)$. Its radius of curvature at the vertex is $\rho=a^2/4b$, therefore $b$ concurs with $a$ in determining the parabola curvature.